# Potent feature in MS apps' "Recent Files" overview

Tags: recent-file-list

I had been viewing an image file "*SomeName.bmp*" in MS Paint (the successor to MS Paintbrush). Then, after closing the Paint session, I went behind its back and changed the filename through Cygwin command

```
mv SomeName.bmp SomeName2012.bmp
```

Then from the Windows 7 Start Button, by right-clicking on the Paint app, I got its "Recent Files" list. It still showed the old filename "*SomeName.bmp*". I clicked to open that one, and automagically it found the proper file "*SomeName2012.bmp*" to open !

Is this intelligence available to all MS VisualStudio developers with the `RecentFiles` list, or is it just MS Paint that is being so smart about it ?

Comment: If you used the list provided by the Start button before the app opened, then it's Windows doing the magic.